# prepareForSegue gets called before ViewDidload in a VC with container view

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a view controller and a `UISearchBar` in the Navigation controller of it. I have added a Container View which then contains 2 ViewControllers.

I need to pass a variable to my Container View and the View Controllers of the Container View. However I can't do that because prepareForSegue happens Earlier than `viewDidLoad()` of my main VC.

I need to pass these variables to my Container View but prepareForSegue gets called before these variables are initialised

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("prepare for segue FirstViewController")

    if segue.identifier == "mapViewContainer" {
       let vc = segue.destination as! MasterMapViewController
       vc.segmentControl = self.container
       vc.resultsViewController = self.resultsViewController
       vc.searchController = self.searchController   
    }
}
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkG27.jpg)

Comment: Any chance you could show what you've tried? Some code? It really helps us to be able to help you.

Comment: I will add some code now :D

Comment: Create a variable to hold a reference to the container's view controller... In prepareForSegue, set that variable to `segue.destination`... in `viewDidLoad()`, you can then use that variable to set data in the contained view controller.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to initialise my variable in the prepareforSegue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to initialize these variables not in the `viewDidLoad`, but in the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: Yep thats what I did and it works perfectly fine. I was wondering if that would cause any trouble ?

Comment: @Persian, you have no choice. You have to prepare for the segue before perform it ;]